# Hiding the media-new.php File URL option via jQuery

Tags: admin, jquery

As the title says I'm currently having some difficulties hiding the File URL option via jQuery.

I've been trying this:

```
// add_action( 'admin_footer-media.php', 'cor_remove_tr_file_url' );
add_action( 'admin_footer-media-new.php', 'cor_remove_tr_file_url' );
/**
 * Removes the 'File URL' row
 */
function cor_remove_tr_file_url() {
?>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('tr.image_url').remove()
});
</script>
<?php
}
```

which works great on `media.php`, but somehow it isn't working on `media-new.php`.

Would someone perhaps know what I might be overlooking here?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because those elements aren't present when the page is finished loading, they're inserted later on using javascript.

Try hooking into #media-items and running your code when new elements are inserted rather than when the root element is ready.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. I'm now using a simple css version to hide things